# No efi system partition found error on a system using MBR drive and Legacy BIOS

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, root, bootloader, mbr

I am very confused why ubuntu is asking for an efi partition. I just created a physical partition with / as the directory. I am trying to dual boot alongside windows.

Comment: Sounds like you booted your installer USB in UEFI mode. Did you by chance create the USB using Rufus with GPT option? If so try MBR option instead.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron Yes, that seemed to be the issue. My crappy BIOS design would not let me boot into the non EFI version straightaway. Still, after installation I encountered "Unable to install grub on sda\dev"  every time.